# How to train for multi-label text classification in Sagemaker?

Tags: text-classification, amazon-sagemaker, multilabel-classification

I have chosen BlazingText algorithm provided by Sagemaker.

Text in my training set can have one or more labels, and I want to predict the most likely labels for an article.

I didn't find how to exactly setup the training file for this. I have made the lines in the training file in the following format

`__label__1 __label__2 token1 token2 ...
__label__2 token token token ...`

Am i doing it right it right?

Comment: the training format seems right! does it return an error?

Comment: No, it doesn't return any error.

Answer (score 2):

Here are possible options for multi-label text classification using SageMaker built-in algorithms including BlazingText:

1. Use a 2-arm embedding model such as [SageMaker Object2vec](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/introduction-to-amazon-sagemaker-object2vec/), that can learn the affinity between a piece of text and an arbitrary number of labels. There actually is a [demo for multilabel text classification here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/object2vec_multilabel_genre_classification/object2vec_multilabel_genre_classification.ipynb)
2. Use one BlazingText instance as a multi-label classifier: at training time, feed multiple space-separated labels per row (didn't try with BlazingText but seems supported with fastText) or all possible label-text pairs, and at inference time ask for the top N predicted labels using the ["k" parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html): `"configuration": {"k": N}`.
3. Use multiple Blazingtext classifiers, one per label. This may be a bit more
   complex to develop than the option above, yet not necessarily more
   expensive given that BlazingText is a very shallow and fast neural
   network

Comment: I am confused. The official docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html says "BlazingText's implementation of the supervised multi-class, multi-label text classification algorithm extends the fastText text classifier...". What does this mean then?

Comment: edited my answer, fastText seems to support multi-label well so chances are BlazingText too (since based on fastText). Object2vec has the advantage of giving you more expressive power (embedding pooling but also conv and bilstm) and also giving you the possibility to get sentence embeddings in addition to label prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, multi-label means that you have multiple labels to classify to, and not that each sentence should have multiple labels in the training set.

If you have for the same sentence multiple labels, you can duplicate the sentence for each label.

Instead of:

```
__label__1 __label__2 token1 token2
```

Use:

```
__label__1 token1 token2 
__label__2 token1 token2
```

In the test or in prediction time for retrieving the top k predictions, you can set k in the configuration:

```
"configuration": {"k": 3}
```

Comment: For k=3, I want the prediction to return probabilities like: __label__1: 0.85 __label__2: 0.75, __label__3: 0.45 . In short, I want the prediction of each label to be independent. If I am to follow your suggestion, BlazingText will treat the prediction as mutually exclusive (probabilities of all lables sum to 1), doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. According to the `sklearn` documentation, "Multiclass classification means a classification task with more than two classes" (which is what you are talking about), whereas "Multilabel classification assigns to each sample a set of target labels", which is what @AayushKarki is asking about. (Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html). 

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the "multiclass" approach that you mention will return probabilities that sum to 1, and will therefore not be independent of each other.